# PHP/MySQL Orders project with items and accessories tables

Tags: php, mysql

**Edited, please see final paragraph.**

I am building a order system that has the following tables and example data:

- **Products**

  - *id*: 1, *Name*: Speaker, *Price*: £12.00
  - *id*: 2, *Name*: Mic, *Price*: £4.00
- **Orders**

  - *id*: 1, *Date*: 2011-01-01
- **Orders_items**

  - *id*: 1, Order_id: 1, Product_id: 1, Qty: 2
  - *id*: 2, Order_id: 1, Product_id: 2, Qty: 1
- **Accessories**

  - id: 1, *Name*: Cable
  - id: 2, *Name*: Mic Stand
  - id: 3, *Name*: Speaker Stand
- **Link_table**

  - id: 1, Product_id: 1, Acc_id: 1, Qty_ship: 2
  - id: 2, Product_id: 1, Acc_id: 3, Qty_ship: 1
  - id: 3, Product_id: 2, Acc_id: 2, Qty_ship: 1

At the moment I use the PHP `while` to write a table containing the line items (no accessories).

Now for the question: I would like to output to a table using PHP that retrieves the line items and also the accessories for that item. Like a pick list.

```
Order 1
Qty Name     Price   Accessories
1   Speaker  £12.00  2 x Cable
                     1 x Speaker stand

1   Mic      £ 4.00  1 x Mic stand
```

Is this possible? The only way i can think about doing it is add a `mysql_query` in the while statement that looks up the accessories when the line item is being written?

## I guess what i am asking is.

```
SELECT * FROM Order_items WHERE Order_id = 1
```

Then at the end of each row i would like to include the results for Accessories

```
SELECT Qty_ship, Acc_id FROM Link_table WHERE Product_id = [NUMBER]
```

Can this be done as one lookup from the database?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a left join on Link_table and Accessories and sort by product_id.

In your while loop, you just need to track if the product_id has changed when echoing the product name.

By the way: You don't need an id field for Link_table, just make product_id and acc_id your primary key.

Comment: ok, thank you Christian. will look at it now and see if i can get it to work. could this method work when calling in PHP?